# XmlWorker does not render nested html list inside itext table

Tags: itext, xmlworker

I'm using itextpdf 5.3.4 and xmlworker 1.2.1. XmlWorker does not support adding nested html list inside itext table. The second level list becomes one line as following.

- item1
- item2 item2.1 item2.2 item 2.3
- item3

I tried to render the nested html list outside the itext table and it works.

Comment: Can you add the code you've tried?

Comment: XML Worker has improved dramatically in the most recent release. Is there a reason why you're not using the most recent release?